# 5_4-2016q3\bin\arm-none-eabi-g++ not found - Windows 10

Tags: c++, azure, azure-iot-hub, azure-iot-central, mxchip

I have created a simple IoT Project using [Azure IoT Device Workbench](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vsciot-vscode.vscode-iot-workbench) extension.

After loading the default configuration I can see the following error on the output window.

```
Loading configuration...
Initializing packages...
Preparing boards...
Verifying...
exec: "/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++": file does not exist
[Warning] Failed to generate IntelliSense configuration.
[Error] Analyzing sketch 'device.ino': Exit with code=1
```

I found that, project has a file named c_cpp_properties.json.  By default `compilerPath` is pointing to `C:\\Users\\heman\\AppData\\Local\\Arduino15\\packages\\AZ3166\\tools\\arm-none-eabi-gcc\\5_4-2016q3\\bin\\arm-none-eabi-g++` but tools folder is empty

**Any idea how can I get this tool installed on my Windows 10 dev machine?**

I found [this](https://github.com/Azure/CloudIoTHack/issues/6) a similar issue and tried to install [IoT DevKit manually](https://microsoft.github.io/azure-iot-developer-kit/docs/installation/) and it didn't help either.

There is a warning message on the manual installation guide which says recommended way to create a new project is through Azure IoT Wrokebench.

[image]

Can't wait to connect my new MXCHIP to Azure IoT Central.

**UPDATE 1**

Found [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-develop/quickstart-devkit-mxchip-az3166-iot-hub) and installed build tools using `get-toolchain.bat` file but still no luck!

Answer (score 1):

This error `exec:"/bin/arm-none-eabi-g++": file does not exist` usually occurs when the required packages and modules are not installed properly.

To resolve this, try uninstalling the existing packages.

Install packages again by making use of below **GitHub reference** in which we have detailed information about:

- Creating IoT Hub
- Registering a Device
- Sending DevKit Telemetry
- Installing Arduino packages, ST-Link Drivers

**Reference:**

[GitHub - Azure-Samples/mxchip-iot-devkit-get-started: This is the GetStarted tutorial for IoT DevKit, please follow the guide to run it in IoT Workbench.](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/mxchip-iot-devkit-get-started#install-visual-studio-code-with-azure-iot-tools-extension-package)